# 'npm i' is not installing @vapnpm vap-dynamic-form package

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to run an angular project locally. When I run the command 'npm i' it gives me the following error

> npm ERR! code E404
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@vapnpm%2fvap-dynamic-form - Not found
> npm ERR! 404
> npm ERR! 404  '@vapnpm/vap-dynamic-form@2.5.0' is not in this registry.
> npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
> npm ERR! 404
> npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
> npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

If i delete this 'vap-dynamic-form' dependency from my package.json then npm i works but on 'ng serve' the project compiles with errors saying

> Cannot find module '@vapnpm/vap-dynamic-form'.

I have added the file manually in my node_modules folder but still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: indeed the package @vapnpm/vap-dynamic-form is not inside npm registry registry.npmjs.org from where come the package ? a local registry ?

Comment: Hi, sorry I am new to this, I don't think there is a local registry. I am trying to run an already completed project on my local to study.

Comment: you said you add manually the module in the folder. From where come the code you add manually ?

Comment: The project runs fine in my colleague's system. he shared it as zip file and told me to keep it in my node_modules

Comment: sure but that not the point from where he recover the package @vapnpm/vap-dynamic-form ? does he have a local registry if he do a `npm config get registry` what it show ?